# NestJS - Transform DTO data to Entity

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a simple User entiy like this:

```
@Entity('users')
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    email: string;

    @Column()
    passwordHash: string;
}
```

and this is CreateUserDto class:

```
export class CreateUserDto {
   @IsEmail()
   email: string

   @IsNotEmpty()
   password: string
}
```

I want to keep `password` field in `CreateUserDto` and auto mappin to the `passwordHash` in `User` entity class. So how can i do that? Please help me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing such as automatic mapping that comes with NestJS. So there are two options you have:

1. Create `user.service.ts` and do the mapping + hashing of the password in there.

```js
create(dto: CreateUserDto) {
  const user = new User();
  user.email = dto.email;
  user.password = createPasswordHash(dto.password); // createPasswordHash fucntion needs to be defined
}
```

2. Use a third party library such as [AutoMapper TypeScript](https://automapperts.netlify.app) that offers automatic mapping functionality (there's also [out-of-the-box NestJS support](https://automapperts.netlify.app/docs/nestjs)).

I suggest to use Automapper if there are large DTOs that need to be mapped (2.), otherwise I would do the mapping manually (1.).

Comment: Thank you, but i want send the request data like this: {“email”: “abc@mail.test”, “password”: “abc” } and it auto mapping to the entity like this: new User(email: “abc@mail.test, passwordHash: “abc”)

Comment: Maybe a transformation pipe is what you want?
https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#transformation-use-case
Otherwise it would be helpful if you would provide a CodeSandbox with a minimal example.